# Charts.js line chart: Show the most recent date on x-axis when setting ticks.maxTicksLimit

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently using making a line chart with Charts.js over the past 30 years.

Although I have a data point for every year, I can't put a label for each year on the x-axis. 30 years won't fit there. So, I've chosen to only list some years, by setting

```
ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: SOME_LIMIT_I_MADE
}
```

Here is a photo of what my chart looks like

[image: Chart Image]

The most recent data point is in 2020 and the oldest is in 1991.

It seems that setting `maxTicksLimit` starts the scale at the earliest year. Then the scale skips forwards in regular intervals.

What I really want is for the most recent year 2020 to be displayed on the scale (so that users can see that the data is new). Is there a way to make the scale start at the max year, and then the skip backwards from there (the opposite of how my graph currently is)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by somehow implement your own [`ticks.maxTicksLimit`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) on the `xAxis`. You would have to proceed as follows.

1. Define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) that accepts the `data` as an array of [data points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) using an object containing `x` and `y` properties.
2. Generate a `labels` array out of the years contained in your data. This array should contain the starting year and end year together with a number of equally spread years between both (see function `createLabels` in the code snippet below).
3. Tell Chart.js to generate `ticks` on the `xAxis` from given labels by defining [`tick.sources: 'labels'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source).

```js
const data = [];
for (let year = new Date().getFullYear() - 29; year <= new Date().getFullYear(); year++) {
  data.push({
    x: year.toString(),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1)
  })
}

const maxTicksLimit = 6;
function createLabels() {
  const years = data.map(o => Number(o.x));
  const startTime = years[0];
  const endTime = years[years.length - 1];
  const tickGap = (endTime - startTime) / (maxTicksLimit - 1);
  const labels = [startTime];
  for (let i = 1; i < maxTicksLimit - 1; i++) {
    labels.push(Math.round(startTime + i * tickGap));
  }
  labels.push(endTime);
  return labels.map(l => l.toString());
}

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: createLabels(),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Demo',
      fill: false,
      data: data,
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'YYYY',
          unit: 'year'
        },
        ticks: {
          source: 'labels'
        }      
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. For anyone else reading this answer, you may have to modify `createLabels()` based on how your graph works. But the key insight is that you should the graph's labels as the x-axis. That is super helpful:)